# Another regex dilemma: exclude all x but not y

Tags: regex

Yet another regex dilemma, I wish to find all X files containing .cc and .h extension which do not contain pb word.

```
Example:
 Foo.cc
 FooTest.cc
 Bar.cc
 Bar.pb.cc
 Bar.pb.h

Regex result:
 Foo.cc
 FooTest.cc
 Bar.cc
```

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: `grep '[.]\(cc\|h\)' file_list | grep -v pb` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
^((?!pb).)*\.(cc|h)$
```

`(?!pb)` is a negative look-ahead that will match any position that is not followed by `pb`.  So `((?!pb).)*` will match any substring that doesn't contain `pb`.  The full regexp can be described as match the whole string provided it ends with '.cc' or '.h' and the substring before the extension does not contain 'pb'.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/cetrCCecsF2d_145)

*Note* that if you want to match a multi-line string you need to add the `(?m)` modifier to your regex that makes `^` and `$` works on each line instead of whole of your string.If your lang doesn't support modifiers use a flag based on the function you used.

Comment: I do particularly enjoy the way you presented your answer. The image helps alot.

Comment: you don't need to check each and every character. It somewhat decreases the performance.

Comment: @Juxhin Glade of that :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Do you mean it needs word boundary?

Comment: @AvinashRaj But this method ports to dialects that disallows arbitrary length lookarounds.

Comment: @Taemyr you mean variable length lookahead. Most languages did support variable length lookaheads but some languages `c#` , `VB.net`, only support variable length lookbehinds . There is nothing wrong with `.*` inside a lookahead.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes. Which is why I said lookarounds.

Comment: Lookarounds means both lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Comment: @Kasra your regex will check for not of `pb` before matching each and every character.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Also, performance is more complicated than you indicate.  Both methods will in principle look for 'pb' at every position in the string.  Your method will be faster for the given examples because regexp is greedy and 'pb' occur late in the string.  I would expect Kasras regexp to perform better for strings where 'pb' tend to occur early in the string.

Comment: @Taemyr yep, mine is greedy . I changed it to non-greedy like `(?!.*?\bpb\b)`. So this would discard the string immediately it finds the substring `pb` but kasra's will check for `pb` before matching each char , what if the a long string which won't actually have the string `pb`. It takes too much time.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Your regexp also checks for 'pb' at every position in the string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yep, you are right but i think in this case and for short strings this is more efficient!

Comment: @AvinashRaj Benchmarking Kasra's regexp and `^(?!.*?pb).*\.(?:cc|h)$` using regexphero.net.  For OP's example strings Kasra is about 50% slower.  For strings of all 'a's Kasras is about 60% slower, independent of the length of string.  (This is sligtly more difference than I expected. I would have guessed a difference of about 20%).  For strings that are on the form a*.h Avinash I was surprised.  This starts with Kasras being about 150% slower (Meaning the other method finished 2.5 times more iterations per second) - And Kasras regexp seems to have worse asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Conclusions of the above: Puting the test at the begining is faster in all cases.  Difference will not be noticable (both regexp runs 100k+ iterations per second) so much more time will be spent in other parts of the program.  There are cases where Kasra's regexp has worse asymptotic behaviour, so for very long input her method should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below negative lookahead based regex.

```
^(?!.*?\bpb\b).*\.(?:cc|h)$
```

`(?!.*\bpb\b)` negative lookahead asserts that the string going to be matched won't contain the word `pb`. If there is no `pb`, then only it tries to match the string and also the string must have `cc` or `h` extension.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xM0hA6/1)

Comment: Why `\bp\b` rather than `\.bp\.` or just `bp`?

Comment: `which do not contain pb word.`, adding word boundaries before and after would satisfy this.

Comment: Fair enough, I think you are reading too much into that sentence though.